# Getting narrower text within lstlistings?

Tags: fonts, listings, fontsize, scaling

I have limited horizontal space to list some code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

and I want to squeeze it horizontally a bit. (Yes, I know in this example it extends to the end of the line; but maybe I have it in a minipage or in a multi-column document etc.)

Now, I don't want to go `\tiny`, just a bit of horizontal squeeze. If I weren't in an `lstlistings` environment, I might [use something like a scalebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67254/stretching-text-vertically), or perhaps [`textls`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136943/scale-font-only-vertically-poor-man-s-condensed-of-libertine), but I don't really have that flexibility (I think) within an lstlistings environment. I'm assuming there must be something I need to put into the `basicstyle` package parameter in `\lstset`; but - what?

Comment: Have you checked the columns option for flexible vs. fixed width?

Comment: @TeXnician: Is that relevant to fixed-width (`\ttfamily`) code?

Comment: can't you just use `\small` ? or choose a different, less wide, monospace font. Squashing it horizontally only sounds like vandalism:-)

Comment: Concerning the column options there's one page in the manual (section 2.10) you should read. But in most cases @DavidCarlisle is right that you might be better off choosing a different font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See edit.

Comment: @TeXnician: See edit, but will also look at that section of the manual.

Comment: You could try setting `\ttdefault` inside `\lstlistings`  to a narrower font. `URW Letter Gothic` seems to be a narrower monospaced font (to be used with the `scaled` option).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377814/indenting-all-lines-of-lists-item-to-the-same-extent#comment936191_377814

Comment: @Bernard: Can you be more explicit? Also, I don't believe I have that font (although I have a bunch of others I suppose I could try).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: There. Sort of an example.

Comment: You could put the listing into a savebox (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378593/control-vertical-spacing-before-empty-minipages/378672#378672) then use \resizebox on \usebox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: A bit of an ugly solution... still, if nothing else works, I might try that.

Answer (score 1):

latin modern for example has light tt that's a bit thinner and condensed tt that's a lot thinner

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\def\lmtt@use@light@as@normal{}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle3}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\footnotesize\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{c}\selectfont,
    keepspaces=true,
}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle2}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\footnotesize\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{m}\selectfont,
    keepspaces=true,
}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keepspaces=true,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{style=mystyle2}
\begin{lstlisting}
C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{style=mystyle3}
\begin{lstlisting}
C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could perhaps use the condensed but increase the font size up from footnotesize....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, with a narrower font, namely URW Letter Gothic (available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/lettergothic/):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
    \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
        language=bash,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        keepspaces=true,
    }
    \lstset{style=mystyle}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\renewcommand\ttfamily{\fontfamily{ulg}\selectfont}}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent\verb|C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)|
    \begin{lstlisting}
    C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily]
    C_10 := elementwise.range_check(C_4,S_5,S_6)
    \end{lstlisting}

    \end{document}
```

[image]